# Loop through array and get row number for each element

Tags: arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, row-number

I am quite new to Google Script, I'm learning on the job. 
I have a range of data as a variable. It's only one column, column F in this case, but there are empty cells between values. I have a working script (got it from here earlier), which only loops through the cells with values in them. So lets say value1 is in F5, value2 is in F13, it's all random and always changing.

I'm trying to get the row number for these values, so that script should give back "5" for value1 and "13" for value2, ideally together with the value itself.

So far, that's what I have and I can not seem to progress further.

```
  var sourceID = "sourceID";
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mainID");
  var mainsheet = main.getSheetByName("Lab Data");
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName("sheet name");
  var dataRange = sourcesheet.getDataRange(); // range full sheet
  var values = dataRange.getValues(); // values full sheet

  var SWrowss = findCellForSW(); // getting start row from another function 
  var CQrowss = findCellForCQ(); // getting last row from another function
  var noRows = CQrowss - SWrowss; // gets number of rows in range
  var colss = sourcesheet.getRange(SWrowss,6,noRows,1).getValues(); // range we need, column F

// get rid of empty cells from range - copied script from stack overflow
  var cResult = colss.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
  return ar;
  }, []);
  Logger.log("cResult:   " + cResult); // cResult contains all sub headers - no empty cells

// gets element's position in array
  for(var b = 0; b < cResult.length; b++){
    var position = b+1;
    Logger.log("pos   " + position);
  } // end for
```

Comment: Have you read about the `reduce` function?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "I can not seem to progress further"? This could mean a lot of different things, so please be specific. Do I understand it correctly that your script can process rows from the Nth value (e.g. rows from 7 to 16) but you need the actual spreadsheet row index for each value?

Comment: I've read about the reduce function from a user on here and it worked for me. 
I couldn't progress with my task, because I wasn't able to retrieve the row number.
Yes, you are correct! It takes a range of rows between 2 headers, depending on where the headers are on the sheet, and I need the actual row index for each value within this range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you want to know the row number, I would propose you a different approach

Just loop through your values and retrieve the position of the ones that are not empty:

```
...
var colss = sourcesheet.getRange(SWrowss,6,noRows,1).getValues();
var rows = [];
var calues = [];
for(var b = 0; b < colss.length; b++){
  if(colss[b][0] != "" && colss[b][0] != " "){
    var row = SWrowss+b+1;
    rows.push(row);
    var value = colss[b][0];
    values.push(value);
  }
}
...
```

Comment: This one works well for me, except it only returns the last value I need - with name and row index, exactly what I need!  I would like it to return (in this case) all 15 values with the row index. Could you please explain how to do it?

Comment: You can e.g.  store all values in rows in arrays - as I just did in my updated answer. There are also other possibilities - depending on how you want to further proceed with this data.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. Apologies for the obvious questions, I'm trying to learn more :)

Answer (score 1):

With the other solution you can build a single object that can do the conversion for you very quickly.

```
var colss = sourcesheet.getRange(SWrowss,6,noRows,1).getValues();
var rvObj={};
for(var b = 0; b < colss.length; b++){
  if(colss[b][0] != "" && colss[b][0] != " "){
   rvObj[colss[b][0]]=SWrowss+b+1;
  }
}
```

With rvObj now you can get any row with `var row = rvObj[value];`

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand how this works. Apologies, I've only started coding from the very beginning roughly a month ago. Could you please explain, how I can get the values back from this?

Comment: var row=rvObj[value]; It’s kind of an array with your values as the keys.